# Symmetric Keys and ASP.NET - storage in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to make absolutely sure I'm implementing my encryption tasks properly. I want to know whether my IV and Key usage is correct.

**Scenario:**

ASP.NET 4.0 Web application which requests and stores end-user email addresses and other personal data. I want to encrypt this information before storing in SQL server. The encryption is to safeguard the data from nosey DBAs and physical theft of the database storage media.

The web application will need to perform tasks on the personal data e.g. send an email to the user, and so it will need to be able to decrypt the values stored in the database.

**Proposal:**

Each time the email address is updated, generate a new IV. Encrypt the email address with the IV and Key (which is the problem). Store the IV and encrypted data in SQL server.

**Question:**

Where do you store the Key?

- Hard-coded in the application? I believe this to be "bad".
- Can it be legitimately stored in the web.config file?

  - If Yes, should I use web.config configuration section encryption? I believe this to be "good".
  - If not, why is it appropriate to store machineKey elements (for ViewState encryption) in web.config?
- Use DPAPI to register a Key with the application pool user account and retrieve on demand?
- Split across various locations e.g. web.config, registry, application code? I believe this to be cumbersome and not necessarily effective.
- Somewhere else.

Am I better off using  the .NET4 MachineKey class to do the encryption/decryption?

I'm hoping a C# code-level solution is appropriate. At present, I can't get my head around column-level SQL Server Encryption, but if you tell me that's the "right way", I'll crack open the books again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, IMHO, the best approach is to use column level encryption in SQL Server. It's transparent to you, and will provide the security level that you're looking for.

Comment: I've looked at Column encryption again, and I just don't see how it stops a DBA from running a query which decrypts the data. What have I missed?

Comment: @NeilMoss Yes, you're right. I was more thinking in external people. Then I'll take DPAPI or web.config options.